# what is the exact mimetype for doc and docx while using ng2FileSelect

Tags: angular, mime-types, ng2-file-upload

Currently, I'm using `ng2FileSelect` for my file uploading in angular 4 projects. I looked up on the internet for the mime-type for allowing doc and docx, after [What is a correct mime type for docx, pptx etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc#4212908) reading through this, I made my changes as per the answer. But still, I'm facing the problem and I'm still unable to upload doc and docx files. Is there any other possible way to do so using `ng2FileSelect`.

> **code**

```
  public allowedMimeType = ['application/pdf','application/msword',
                            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'];

  attachment: FileUploader = new FileUploader({
    allowedMimeType: this.allowedMimeType,
  });
```

this code is helping me only in the upload of pdf files, not with doc and docx.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with `ng2-file-upload` (and I think it can be `multer` problem, not `ng2-file-upload`). 
But when i download `.docx`, my app understand it not like `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`, but like `application/octet-stream`.

I can't find 'right' solution and can't answer why it happened, but when I start to use `application/octet-stream` in my MIME checking - all works fine (for `.doc`, `.docx` and etc.)

You can read about `application/octet-stream` on MDN
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#Discrete_types

I think it less security solution, but it working and it better than nothing :)

Comment: 2020 and nothing change some kind of docx can not recognized only as application/octet-stream